# Django rest framework http 404 detail": "Not found."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Whenever I try to update an itinerary with primary key using PUT request I get HTTP 404 detail": "Not found."

api views.py

```
class updateTempItinerary(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = tempItinerary.objects.all()
    serializer_class = tempItinerarySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
```

api urls.py

```
url(r'^updatetempitinerary/$(?P<pk>)(?P<itineraryID>)(?P<destinations>)(?P<hotels>)', views.updateTempItinerary.as_view()),
```

itinerary models.py

```
class tempItinerary(models.Model):
    itineraryID = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.IntegerField()
    destinations = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='None')
    hotels = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='None')
    travelClass = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    travelers = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s ' % (self.pk, self.travelers, self.date, self.travelClass, self.hotels, self.destinations, self.country, self.itineraryID, self.user)
```

URL im testing on

```
127.0.0.1:8000/api/updatetempitinerary/?pk=1&format=json&
```

Comment: it seems you are missing a couple arguments in the url?

Answer (score 1):

As Booby suggested your url is wrong. If you are using PUT request I suggest your that your remove your url arguments except id. So it will look like so: `url(r'^updatetempitinerary/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.updateTempItinerary.as_view()),` That is all (**notice there is a $ sign at the end)**.

If this does not work please provide your serializers and full error traceback. You can update your model on `127.0.0.1:8000/api/updatetempitinerary/1/`.